# Why is one of the lines / edges visible on my mirror

Tags: modeling

All edges / phases have been created in the same way, by the extrusion tool. So I do not understand why one of them seems to be unique.

Can anyone help me understand what is happening here?[image]

Here is my project file

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you (try to) select one of the triangles defined by the problematic edge, you will see that it's actually a quad:

[image]

So the edge there is not defining any face. Blender doesn't display edges defining faces in *Object Mode*, but it does display edges that don't define a face. In a way your problem proves the usefulness of this approach, as thanks to that, you noticed a problem with your topology.

You can simply select the edge and press <kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>E</kbd> to remove it. If you want to divide this quad into two triangles, then **after removing current edge** select appropriate vertices and press <kbd>J</kbd> to *Join* them. This will cut through the existing face like with a *knife* tool, instead of adding an edge on top of existing topology without changing it.

[image]

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this is a wrong answer but I decided to leave it for people coming from Google in future, as it might be correct for them.

Probably, judging from this line being slightly different than other lines (edges), it is actually an empty space between two faces. Which means that in the red circle on the right, there are 4 vertices, not 2.

Pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>M</kbd>, then <kbd>B</kbd>, expanding the *Merge by Distance* popup in bottom-left corner and adjusting the *distance* slider, will probably fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changes. "0 vertices removed". 

Updated my post with the project file

Answer (score 0):

You should make a new edge between the two points by pressing  <kbd>J</kbd> instead of  <kbd>F</kbd>.